# Not able to access array in ajax response in setInterval

Tags: php, json, jquery

I've function which send a request to server every 5 second. I have send two array variables in ajax request. to get result. How ever I'm not able to access second array in response. check my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

sectionIds=<?php echo json_encode($blocksection);?>;
currProcessing=<?php echo json_encode($process_section); ?>;

    function init()
    {
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log(sectionIds);
            console.log(currProcessing);
            $.post('ajax_comet.php',{sectionIds:sectionIds,currProcessing:currProcessing},function (data){
            console.log(sectionIds);
            console.log(currProcessing);

            },'json');

        }, 5000);
    } 
    </script>
```

It is important to assign those arrays outside the function.
Insite init(). I'm getting both array value, but in response I'm not able to get cussProcessing values, It shows undefined in console. Showing sectionIds Properly.

Nothing wrong with PHP file too. I just want to access "currProcessing" inside response. Don't even need it on PHP page.

What exactly going wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean? `currProcessing` is a value before `$.post`. But in the callback it is `undefined`?

Comment: yes exactly before it shows ["1"] which is correct, but in response its undefined.

Comment: Please ensure that you use the `var` keyword for **every** variable declaration, regardless of whether or not you want them to be members of the topmost object and no matter how well you understand the implications of not using it. Failing to explicitly declare variables is code smell.

Comment: What other scripts do you have on the page? In isolation the code you show does not seem to have any way to cause this problem. However, it is possible that some other code on your page is reassigning these variables after `init()` is called and before the response is received from the server.